# Does Bishul Akum Apply To Half-Siblings

Tags: halacha, gentiles, family-members, intermarriage, bishul-akum

Speaking to a Rabbi recently he told me the rules of *Bishul Aqum* have more to do with preventing intermarriage than risk of non kosher ingredients being added to food without a Jew's knowledge.

Let's say someone has a Jewish mother and non Jewish father and has half siblings through the father. These siblings are not Jewish, but if one was raised with these siblings and viewed them as family, do the rules of Bishul Aqum apply to these siblings and make it forbidden to eat food cooked by them since there seems to be no risk of intermarriage?

Comment: Do we have any examples of subjectivity in this regard? It's not like male gentiles don't effect Bishul Akum for male Jews

Comment: In such a case where darkei shalom absolutely applies, it seems one could rely on the Rama's ruling l'chatchila regarding fire and possibly the Rashba's(?) ruling not requiring fire in a Jewish house(this needs more investigation since the father is not Jewish). See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 113:4, 6, & 7. This needs the judgement of a competent and understanding posek.

Comment: There should be no reason to allow it (barring other considerations - perhaps darchei Shalom).  You don't need to think up lots of examples where there is absolutely no reason to think that Jew X would have relations with non-Jew Y, and still it would be forbidden.  For example, can a ger eat his parents' food made by them, even if kashrus considerations were not relevant?  No.  The intention of Chazal would be a *lo plug* - even when the reasons don't necessarily apply.  Also, it would only help for the persons concerned - the food would be assur to Jews outside of that circle?

Answer (score 2):

First of all Bishul Akum Food cooked by a gentile applies even if there is no worry of intermarriage Rema Yore Dea 112,1:

> אסרו חכמים לאכול פת של עובדי כוכבים, משום חתנות. (**ואפילו במקום דליכא משום חתנות**, אסור) (רשב"א סימן רמ"ח)

Secondly, since a Gentile according to Halacha is allowed to marry a sibling who shares a common father but not a common mother there is concern of marriage in this situation.
 Rambam Hilchot Melachim 9,5 says:
שש עריות אסורות על בני נח:
האם ואשת האב ואשת איש ואחותו מאמו וזכור ובהמה
This means his sister from his father might want to marry him as they are not related according to Halacha of bnei Noach (it might not bother her that he is forbidden to her because he's Jewish and shes not) and if she converts they would be able to marry each other as stated in Shulchan Aruch 269,3 (though a convert cannot marry a sister from the mother). Indeed Tamar wanted to marry Amnon her brother through her father Shmuel 2 13,13 she was conceived when her mother was not Jewish yet (see Sanhedrin 21a from here we learn that Yichud is prohibitted)

Thirdly in this situation, this sister probably hangs out with gentile friends so even if she personally feels repulsed to marry him he can still frequent her friends/relatives at meals which she cooks.

Comment: I haven't down voted your answer but I find some flaws from the premise. Just because Torah law doesn't forbid gentiles from sleeping with certain siblings doesn't mean the rest of the gentile world follows that. Many cultures would never do such a thing.

Comment: @aaron thank you for getting back to me.First of all my main arguement is based on the Shach that Chazal didn't make exceptions with regards to Bishul Akum. while what you are saying might 
hav ereppurcussions about hilchos yichud to live with half nonjewish sister (though it could be one is forforbidden i don't know if socsiety norms affect yichud) Bishul akum is not dependent on logic. I also mentioned that a non Jewish sister will cook for friends and family who are also not Jewish and can cause intermarriage.

Comment: @aaron see my edit i brought the story of Amnon and Tamar as a proof that there is attraction between half siblings according to the gemora